# Nginx forwards request to local IP

Tags: web-services, nginx, local

It's the first time I really work with nginx so please forgive me if I misuse terminology here.

So our companies network has a static IP to which I send requests from multiple sub-domains:

```
jitsi.domain.ext -> public IP
sub2.domain.ext -> public IP
...
```

Those requests pass through the firewall and port forwarding to my dedicated nginx server and shall be routed from there to other local servers like so:

```
jitsi.domain.ext -> local server (jitsi server)
sub2.domain.ext -> local server (website)
...
```

For this I created besides the untouched global config a separate config for each subdomain and put it in

`/etc/nginx/sites-available` and via `ln -s` linked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

like so:

```
# jitsi.domain.ext

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert/jitsiCert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert/jitsiKey.pem;

    server_name jitsi.domain.ext;
    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.139;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The config is called just fine but it literally redirects me to the URL "192.168.0.139" in the browser. Which of course doesn't work when I am outside of the network and want to access it.

The .pem I use is the one I created for the Jitsi server. I figured that's the easiest way to do it since the dedicated Jitsi server uses nginx as well and I don't want to tamper with it to not break any future updates it gets.

If anyone has a clue for me, I'd be grateful. I tried to get something out of the docs and countless other similar issues discussed on the internet, but nothing seemed to do the trick for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This config should not redirect you to `192.168.0.139` unless this redirect is generated by your upstream. Try appending `proxy_set_header Host jitsi.domain.ext;` to your config. Do you really need `proxy_redirect off;`?

Comment: Thanks for the input! With redirect on the config cannot be loaded and without that line at all I get "too many redirections" error in browser.

Comment: That's the reason to debug and adjust redirection rewrite rules, not to completely turning them off. Temporary remove this `proxy_redirect off;` directive, run `curl -I jitsi.domain.ext` and show its output.

Comment: It says `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently [..] Location: https://jitsi.domain.ext/` with and without the `proxy_redirect off;`

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any HTTP to HTTPS redirections in your config. Maybe you just omit that part for simplicity? Ok, what's `curl -I https://jitsi.domain.ext/` output?

Comment: Both with `proxy-redirect off;` and without it I get `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. Browser still complains about too many redirects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217441/discussion-between-ivan-shatsky-and-anonjnr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Ivan Shatsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7121513/ivan-shatsky) I came to realise that the "problem" indeed is the redirection of jitsi's nginx and not the configuration of my "gateway" nginx.

[Russel August](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812726/russellaugust) helped me solve that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194598/how-to-verify-nginx-ssl-that-is-forwarding-to-another-nginx-that-also-needs-veri?noredirect=1#comment111090135_61194598) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1542268/hitting-a-wall-with-nginx-ssl-forwarding/1542637#1542637).